# Why are my public URLS from Assets returning http instead of https?

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, email-template, content-assets

I have images in my Assets library that I'd like to display in my Visualforce Email templates. To do this I have created some functions in my VF Controller like this:

```
public String orgId {
    get {
        return '?oid=' + UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
    }
}

public String domain {
    get {
        String domain = URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm();
        domain.replace('http://', 'https://');
        return domain + '/file-asset-public/';
    }
}

public String logo {
    get {
        Map<String, String> testMap = new Map<String, String>();
        for (ContentAsset assetFile : [SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, DeveloperName FROM ContentAsset WHERE DeveloperName = 'company_logo' ]) 
        {
            for (String imageId : this.imageSource.keySet()) {
                if(assetFile.DeveloperName == this.imageSource.get(imageId))
                testMap.put(imageId, this.domain + assetFile.ContentDocumentId + orgId);
            }
        }
        // there will only ever be one record
        return testMap[0];
    }
}
```

This is able to generate my links so they look like this:
`https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/file-asset-public/069XXXXXXXXX?oid=00DYYYYYYYYYYY`

The problem is, when I view the email in the classic emails page and merge with some data... the image urls are in `HTTPS` which is what I'm expecting, however when the emails are sent to real users/contacts via automation, all the content URLS are in `HTTP`.

You can see in my controller I have tried to rashly replace http with https but this doesn't appear to have any affect.

Can someone explain why this occurs and how I can fix this?